# Sorting and Filtering multiple queries of the same collection in Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I'm new on cloud firestore and I'm trying to make queries as efficient as possible but I kind of desperate with an specific one. I would greatly appreciate your help.

This is the situation:

I want to show a project list which that I'm getting from an user field and 2 queries in project entity. The user field let’s called "favorite projects" and it has the projects id that reference those projects on their entity. The other query retrieve me the public projects (==) and the last the private projects where the user is a contributor (array_contains).

I want to sort and filtering the result of the two queries. Is there an option to merge both queries and use sort and filter as a we do with a collection reference?
Thank you for your time, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#query_limitations) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data) documentation, I do not believe there is an out of the box solution for joining the results of queries such as the ones described.

You'll need to achieve that within the your code.

For example you can run the first query and store all the data of the document in a map or array. Then use the reference of the other document within the document_reference to make the second query and the third.

Once you have all of them you can do as you please using Python. But getting them ready using a single query or auto-joining the queries seems to not be supported yet.